starttime and endtime are not existing in robot framework output.xml file
I tried to parse test result of Robot Framework to postgres by using TestArchiver (TestArchiver) but the below error occurred:
Parsing: 'output.xml'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/testarchiver", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
             ^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/test_archiver/output_parser.py", line 861, in main
    build_number_cache = parse_xml(output_file, args.format, connection, config, build_number_cache)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/test_archiver/output_parser.py", line 795, in parse_xml
    parser.feed(buffer)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 211, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, isFinal)
  File "/Users/sysadmin/build/v3.12.0/Modules/pyexpat.c", line 416, in StartElement
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/xml/sax/expatreader.py", line 327, in start_element
    self._cont_handler.startElement(name, AttributesImpl(attrs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/test_archiver/output_parser.py", line 91, in startElement
    self.archiver.begin_status(attrs.getValue('status'), attrs.getValue('starttime'),
                                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/xml/sax/xmlreader.py", line 291, in getValue
    return self._attrs[name]
           ~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
KeyError: 'starttime'

I used command:
testarchiver --format robot --allow-major-schema-updates --dbengine postgresql --user postgres --pw ******* --database robot_test output.xml

And I tried looking in output.xml but there is no keyword starttime and endtime too.

Its most likely due to changes in RF 7.0 and TestArchiver has not been updated to handle that. Part of the issue is that the organisation "Salabs" that wrote that tool does not exists anymore at least in way it used to.

The root of the problem are version of Robot Framework which I has try to downgrade from Robot Framework 7.0 to 6.0.1 and problem are fixed.
